# Validating registration form, span element not being filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a registration page and i have jquery so if an element isn't filled in or passwords don't match then it should put some text into the span element next to the element.

At the moment it doesn't seem to be updating the span and i cant see why. I will also be doing client side on this after doing my JS before people say to do that.

I have created a fiddle, I need to change the JS as i only have one spanclass for each row now but i can't get it to work.

Help would be appreciated.

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/e9gs4/

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <input type="password" name="repassword" id="password" class="password" placeholder="Confirm Password"><span class"val_pass2"></span></br>
```

Comment: Better use http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: first change the id of any one element. Your both element have same id.

Comment: The jQuery works as i have used it before, however i cant get the writing to come up and say theres an error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a syntax error in span. Use **=** to declare class

```
<span class="abc">
```

Answer (score 0):

When testing for empty password or repassword, you are using a single equals sign instead of a double, meaning you are assigning the empty value to both password and repassword instead of comparing to it. Should be like this

```
if (password == "") {
```

and this...

```
if (repassword == "") {
```

Also, you are missing an equals sign in some of your spans. Should be like this:

```
<span class="val_pass2">
```